# How to Create a Pager Indicator below each items in recycler view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter, mobile-application

I have created a `recycler view`  containing  a list of items , for example options like  `Home, contacts` `profile` with the help of Adapter.  so currently on clicking each of the  items in recycler view, I'm passing the callback back to the fragment using interface  for respective actions. On clicking each of the icons in recycler view , I'm opening a fragment class. This is what I was implementing for my application. so now  I have to show a `page indicator` in the form of a Line below each of the selected icons. How can we implement the indicator upon selection of each icons??

Sample Code :

```
 List<FilterCategories>  filterCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    filterCategories.add(new FilterCategories("Home", R.drawable.filter_price_gray, 0));
    filterCategories.add(new FilterCategories("Contacts", R.drawable.filter_store_gray, 0));
    filterCategories.add(new FilterCategories("Profile", R.drawable.filter_style_gray, 0));


filterByAdapter = new FilterByAdapter(getContext(), filterCategories);
filterRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
filterRecycler.setAdapter(filterByAdapter);
```

Comment: Can you provide a picture or something to exactly show what you want?

Comment: @amirho3einRostami - I was able to resolve the issue, with the below sample code.

Comment: You should upvote questions that solved your problems so future visitors can know that the answer solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to  show the pager indicator by creating a custom `View` inside the XML layout of the adapter. I have used the `view` to hide and show, by clicking on each of the item view in recycler on bindViewHolder.

sample code :

```
private void handleClick(ViewHolder holder, final String title, int position) {
    holder.itemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(viewClick);
            for (int i = 0; i < filterCategories.size(); i++) {
                if (i == position ){
                    filterCategories.get(i).setSelectedSlider(true);
            
                }else{
                    filterCategories.get(i).setSelectedSlider(false);
                    
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
           // viewTap(title);
        }
```

```
 if (filterCategories.get(position).isSelectedSlider()) {
            holder.sliderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.sliderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Model class code :

```
public class FilterCategories {

    private String   Title;
    private int      Images;
    private boolean  isExpanded       = false;
    private boolean  isSelectedSlider = false;
    private Integer  BadgeCount;

    public FilterCategories() {

    }

    public FilterCategories(String title, int images ,int badgeCount) {

        Title = title;
        Images = images;
        BadgeCount = badgeCount;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public int getImages() {
        return Images;
    }

    public void setImages(int images) {
        Images = images;
    }

    public boolean getExpanded() {
        return isExpanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        isExpanded = expanded;
    }
    public Integer getBadgeCount() {
        return BadgeCount;
    }

    public void setBadgeCount(Integer badgeCount) {
        BadgeCount = badgeCount;
    }

    public boolean isSelectedSlider() {
        return isSelectedSlider;
    }

    public void setSelectedSlider(boolean selectedSlider) {
        isSelectedSlider = selectedSlider;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).